# How to make an always running app such as "Advanced task cleaner"?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

As the title, how can I make an android app which can run persistently at the background? I found an similar app at android market, that is "Advanced task cleaner pro". It's always running. If I force stop it, it is killed. But some seconds later, I see that it runs again.

Any solution for me?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: Ah. Then the particular techniques that your cited app uses have been blocked as of Android 3.1. If you were seeing this on an Android 3.1+ device, then I would be worried that they were exploiting some new security loophole and would need to research it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AlarmManager to periodically wake your app upp.

Comment: Alarms are eliminated by a force-stop, though.